# Shell function is working on different path in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, shell

I have a code written in C++ generates an "a.exe" file put it under D:\Test. The code will read a txt file also put it under D:\Test.
If I execute a.exe directly, there will be no problem. I can use getcwd to check that the path of exe is also in D:\Test.

But if use vba `r=shell("D:\Test\a.exe",1)`. When I went to execute it, I found that the path of the exe checked using getcwd was changed to C:..\My Documents.
As long as you use SHELL to execute the EXE directory, it will run to MY DOCUMENTS.

I don’t want to fix the path because this VBA program needs to be used on different computers. Is there any other solution? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I got solved!! I just added `ChDrive ThisWorkbook.Path`